# Using value_counts() and filter elements based on number of instances

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I use the following code to create two arrays in a histogram, one for the counts (percentages) and the other for values.

```
df = row.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)
counts = df                   # contains percentages
values = df.keys().tolist()
```

So, an output looks like

```
counts = 66.7, 8.3, 8.3, 8.3, 8.3
values = 1024, 356352, 73728, 16384, 4096
```

Problem is that some values exist one time only and I would like to ignore them. In the example above, only 1024 repeated multiple times and others are there only once. I can manually check the number of occurrences in the `row` and see if they are not repeated multiple times and ignore them.

```
df = row.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(1)
counts = df                   # contains percentages
values = df.keys().tolist()
for v in values:
    # N = get_number_of_instances in row
    # if N == 1
    #    remove v in row
```

I would like to know if there are other ways for that using the built-in functions in Pandas.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are yo happy to provide a sample of the df you are using?

Comment: `df.keys().to_list()`, put df columns into a list. Are you suggesting you want drop non duplicated columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some clarity requested on your question in comments above

If keys is a column and you want to retain non duplicates, please try

```
values=df.loc[~df['keys'].duplicated(keep=False), 'keys'].to_list()
```